# JSF2/Richfaces4 not loading contents of .ecss files

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I'm upgrading to Richfaces 4 and the Sun implementation of JSF2 (2.0.6) from Richfaces 3.3 and JSF 1.2.

My css files are under 'WebContent/resources/css'.

When pages get rendered, all .css files get loaded correctly.

For some reason the content of my .ecss files do not get loaded, any ideas why this is?

Do I need some extra settings in my web.xml?

```
<h:head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml" charset="UTF-8" />

  <title><ui:insert name="pageTitle" /> - </title>

  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="broken.ecss" />
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="works.css" />

</h:head>
```

broken.ecss:

```
p {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Looking at firebug, the styles in broken.ecss are not been found.

---

One thing I did notice is the path to the files. My css files have the JSF2 resources path while ecss files have the Richfaces resources path. Could this be the issue (Seen as I have all my files under the default JSF2 resources location)?

```
/AppPath/rfRes/common.ecss.jsf?db=eAHTLYlbCQADeQGp&amp;ln=css
/AppPath/javax.faces.resource/style.css.jsf?ln=issuer/bla
```

Also, the following is shown in logs:

```
"GET /AppPath/rfRes/common.ecss.jsf?db=eAHTLYlbCQADeQGp&ln=css HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

### UPDATE

Ok, the 302 was due to a redirect for errors I had in my web.xml. Now I can see the true cause of the problem:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/WebApp] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser
```

Do I need to include some sort of CSSOMParse jar in my app also?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK.....I download and added the cssParser-0.9.5.jar to my webApp and it fixed the problem!

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cssparser/files/cssparser/0.9.5/cssparser-0.9.5.jar/download

I originally had the following jar which I thought was all that was needed for the Richfaces4 upgrade: sac-1.0.0.1.jar.

There seems to be no mention of adding the cssParser jar to projects when upgrading to Richfaces 4, is there a reason for this or am I missing something here?

I'm getting more frustrated by the day with Richfaces limited examples, documentation and more importantly a large enough community to answer questions like these :(